# Applying Quillen's small object argument to a specific morphism

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

I've been learning about model category theory and cofibrant generation of model structures, and I've come across Quillen's small object argument. In the informal paper I'm writing I'm choosing to omit the proof of the small object argument, but instead I wanted to show an example of explicitly using the small object argument to construct a factorisation of a morphism but I don't really know where to start or how to do it?

I'd like to apply it to a simple morphism in $\textbf{Cat}$, the category of small categories,  since I've used it as an example to demonstrate several other things in the paper. Perhaps to the functor $\textbf{1} \rightarrow \textbf{2}$, where $\textbf1$ is the one object category and $\textbf2$ is the two object category with one non-trivial isomorphism.

Any advice on how to approach this problem would be very much appreciated!

edit: I'm using the canonical model structure:
W is the class of category equivalences;
Cof is the class of functors that inject on objects;
Fib is the class of isofibrations: [link](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/isofibration)

Comment: What's your model structure?

Comment: Ah whoops, I'm using the canonical model structure;
W is the class of category equivalences;
Cof is the class of isocofibrations: functors that inject on objects;
Fib is the class of isofibrations: see [link](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/isofibration)

Cheers!

Comment: This is an unusual thing to do. The small object argument doesn't have output that's well defined up to isomorphism, you just stop gluing at some point you have to choose. It's rarely used explicitly, if ever. In Cat, the factorizations are pretty easy to understand without the small object argument, so I'm not sure it would be very enlightening.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I hadn't thought about it like that... But I can't think what else might be appropriate to put in the paper; the proof is significantly too long and I only have a page or two left. Do you have any suggestions?  
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Seb It depends on what else you're doing. If you're not going to actually construct a model structure relying on the SOA, you could just leave it out and give more examples of explicit factorizations. Otherwise you could give a sketch construction, perhaps for an arbitrary map of spaces.